# Dynamically Linking Python Extension (.pyd) to Another Extension

Tags: python, distutils, dynamic-linking

Python Extension modules are just dynamic libraries, so I assume it's possible to dynamically link a Python extension to another. The problem is on Windows Python Extensions are are given the `.pyd` extension instead of `.dll`, so I can't get distutils to link to them when I run the setup script. (I don't think this is a problem on UNIX because Python extensions use the `.so` file extension.)

Assume I have an extension `bar.pyd` which needs to link to `foo.pyd`. Basically, what I did in the setup script was:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

foo = Extension("foo", sources=["foo.c"])
bar = Extension("bar", libraries=["foo"], sources=["bar.c"])
setup(ext_modules=[foo, bar])
```

So far this isn't working. Is this even possible? I assume it is, but I haven't been able to find anything online. I'm using MinGW on Windows, but I would like this to work with different MSVC++ and on other systems as well.

**Edit:** Previously, I solved this problem by passing the object file (`foo.o`) created when `foo` was compiled to the `extra_objects` option in the extension (this would only work if I defined prototypes of all `foo` symbols in `bar`):

```
bar = Extension("bar", sources=["bar.c"], extra_objects=["build/.../foo.o"]
```

This didn't seem to be the right solution, but it worked. I don't understand dynamic linking that well, so this may be the right way to do it. It feels very wrong, though.

Then, I tried passing some explicit arguments to gcc to make it compile an import library:

```
foo = Extension("foo", sources=["foo.c"], extra_compile_args=["-Wl,--out-implib,foo.lib,--export-all-symbols"])
```

And then I linked `bar` to the new import library:

```
bar = Extension("bar", libraries=["foo"], sources=["bar.c"])
```

This compiled without complaint, but there were some issues with some of the symbols (specifically, I had a few global `PyTypeObject`s in `foo` that seemed to be redefined in `bar`. I need the `PyTypeObject`s in both modules refer to the same definition.).

**Edit 2:** So, I singled out the problem. Function symbols were exporting correctly after I built and linked against the import libraries, but the `PyTypeObject`s were getting redeclared. Assume there was a `PyTypeOject Foo_Type` in `foo`. I declared it in `foo.h`, which was included in both `foo.c` and `bar.c`:

```
PyTypeObject Foo_Type;
```

I took that out, and put this near the top of `foo.c`:

```
PyTypeObject __declspec(dllexport) Foo_Type;
```

and this near the top of `bar.c`:

```
PyTypeObject __declspec(dllimport) Foo_Type;
```

That fixed the problem. I could then use Foo_Type in both `foo` and `bar` and it referred to the same definition of Foo_Type. The problem is, this isn't going to work on non-Windows systems. I assume if I just take the `__declspec`s out, it'll work fine on other systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the normal Python [import mechanisms](http://docs.python.org/c-api/import.html) then there's no need to link against the other extension. If you're calling functions within the other extension, presumably because you have gotten a hold on the header file, then you'll need to generate an import lib from the DLL before you can link against it.

Comment: Both of these extension modules are part of my project, so I would like to link between them instead of using the Python import mechanisms. I'm pretty new at this, though, so I'm not quite sure how to generate the import lib. Can you shed some light on this?

Answer (score -3):

```
from distutils.core import Extension as cExtension
from pyd.support import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension("x", sources = ['xclass.c'])
module2 = Extension("y", sources = ['hello.d'], build_deimos=True)

setup(
    name = "x",
    version = '1.0',
    description = "eat a taco",
    ext_modules = [
        module1,
        module2
    ]
);
```

from : http://pyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with the D programming language.

Comment: `pyd` in the question title refers to "python dll", not "The D programmning language for Python"