# Link against another python C extension

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, python-c-api

I have two python extensions written in C:

- `foo.bar.libbar` defined in `foo/bar/bar.c`
- `foo.baz.libbaz` defined in `foo/baz/baz.c`

`libbar` depends on symbols from `libbaz`, namely a non-python-exported function called `doubleint`.

The setup.py for the library looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension

setup(
        name="mylib",
        packages=find_packages(),
        ext_modules=[
            Extension("foo.baz.libbaz",
                sources=["foo/baz/baz.c"],
                ),
            Extension("foo.bar.libbar",
                sources=["foo/bar/bar.c"],
                include_dirs=['foo/baz']
                ),
            ],
        )
```

Then there is the header files:

`foo/baz/baz.h`:

```
int doubleint(int a);
```

and the two C files:
`foo/baz/baz.c`:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

#include "baz.h"

int doubleint(int a){
    return a * 2;
}

static PyObject *myfunction(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    printf("inside python baz\n");
    printf("double of %d is %d\n", 2, doubleint(2));
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"myfunction", myfunction, METH_VARARGS, "does stuff"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef module = {
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "libbaz", NULL, -1, methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_libbaz(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&module);
}
```

`foo/bar/bar.c`:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

#include "baz.h"

static PyObject *otherfunction(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
    printf("inside python bar\n");
    printf("double of %d is %d\n", 2, doubleint(2));
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"otherfunction", otherfunction, METH_VARARGS, "does same stuff"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

static struct PyModuleDef module = {
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "libbar", NULL, -1, methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_libbar(void) {
    return PyModule_Create(&module);
}
```

If I now call `python setup.py build`, everthing builds fine, there are no compile errors:

```
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo
copying foo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/baz
copying foo/baz/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/baz
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/bar
copying foo/bar/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/bar
running build_ext
building 'foo.baz.libbaz' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/baz
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/home/user/mytest/venv/include/python3.5m -c foo/baz/baz.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/baz/baz.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/baz/baz.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/baz/libbaz.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
building 'foo.bar.libbar' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/bar
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Ifoo/baz -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/home/user/mytest/venv/include/python3.5m -c foo/bar/bar.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/bar/bar.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,relro -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/bar/bar.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/bar/libbar.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Now I can start up an interpreter and load `foo.baz.libbaz` and call `myfunction`. But if I want to import `foo.bar.libbar` I get an error:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from foo.baz import libbaz
>>> libbaz.myfunction()
inside python baz
double of 2 is 4
>>> from foo.bar import libbar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/user/mytest/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/foo/bar/libbar.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: doubleint
```

I can see, that the library is not linked against `libbaz`:

```
$ ldd foo/bar/libbar.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd2d821000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb8850a0000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb884d01000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb8854bf000)
```

I can work around this problem my adding `foo/baz/baz.c` to the `sources` of `libbar` but I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

I also tried to set `runtime_library_dirs=['$ORIGIN/../baz']` which did not helped either. I assume I would have to tell the linker to link against the library, but how do you specify this? I tried many library names like `libbaz`, `baz`, `foo.baz.libbaz`, `foo.baz.baz` but none of them work with ld, as it can not find the library.

I read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270302/446140 to a similar question which says you should create a separate import library, but how would this work in the context of `Extension` then? How could I build the library first and then link it against the extensions?

Comment: You have a couple of possibilities here: share functionality between modules as static library (probably best to put doubleint into a separate cpp, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/57673283/5769463) or (more correctly) as shared object/dll (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63875206/5769463) or provide the functionality a way similar to Cython's way of exposing its `cdef` functions (here is a starting point/overview: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58155766/5769463)

Comment: I have same question as you, did you figure out how to resolve that?

Comment: @Suen no, it looks like this is not endorsed and shall not be done... Probably the best way would be to write a separate library and link against that as ead suggested.